# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null, Ionic App + Webpack+ Viewport Resizer

Tags: ionic-framework, viewport

I'm trying to view Ionic App in Apple iPhone 5 size by using viewport resizer. It worked nicely before I compressed Ionic library files with webpack. But after compressing when I tried to use viewport I'm getting an error like

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null     ionic.bundle.js:42368

in chrome and getting a blank page. The code area where the error occurred is

```
  var el = jqLite('<div class="backdrop">');
  var backdropHolds = 0;
  $document[0].body.appendChild(el[0]);
```

I think the document body changes when the resizer window appears and then $document is picking a wrong window.

Is there any way to overcome this problem so that I can user viewport resizer for Ionic App? Thanks in advance.